# In the context of America's espionage infrastructure, what is NE?

Tags: united-states, cia

I was listening to an agent of America's *Central Intelligence Agency* discuss their operations in Afghanistan in the 1980s and she mentioned subdivisions of their "intelligence community" by the abbreviations NE and SAD.

SAD is Special Activities Division. What is NE?

Comment: Closest I can find [is this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hb8xAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=N.E.+espionage&source=bl&ots=5aZgvtOlbw&sig=TzvTA7ZFGWq0tP8z8m5Ooo5wGDE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=N.E.%20espionage&f=false); it's difficult to say if this is what they intended without more context though.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes that has to be it. This is all of the context but that makes total sense. I have even heard of that before now that you mention it. You should make that an official answer.

Comment: "I was listening to an agent..." Where were you listening?

Comment: @Trilarion Hacked her email. Or maybe it was on *The Americans*. Hard to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The division you are looking for is almost certainly the CIA "Near East" Division, as mentioned in [this](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2007/11/18/AR2007111800675.html) Washington Post article detailing secret operations in Afghanistan by the Special Activities Division (SAD) and the Near East Division. A chart of CIA divisions can be found [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Organizational_Chart_of_the_CIA_National_Clandestine_Service.png).

Comment: Thank you, Comrade. I know that many Bothans died to bring us this information :)